# PostgreSQL SELECT date before max(DATE)

Tags: postgresql, date, max, intervals

I need to select the rows for which the difference between max(date) and the date just before max(date) is smaller than 366 days. I know about `SELECT MAX(date) FROM table` to get the last date from now, but how could I get the date before?

I would need a query of this kind:

```
SELECT code, MAX(date) - before_date FROM troncon WHERE MAX(date) - before_date < 366 ;
```

NB : `before_date` does not refer to anything and is to be replaced by a functionnal stuff.

**Edit :** Example of the table I'm testing it on:

```
CREATE TABLE troncon (code INTEGER, ope_date DATE) ;

INSERT INTO troncon (code, ope_date) VALUES
('C086000-T10001', '2014-11-11'),
('C086000-T10001', '2014-11-11'),
('C086000-T10002', '2014-12-03'),
('C086000-T10002', '2014-01-03'),
('C086000-T10003', '2014-08-11'),
('C086000-T10003', '2014-03-03'),
('C086000-T10003', '2012-02-27'),
('C086000-T10004', '2014-08-11'),
('C086000-T10004', '2013-12-30'),
('C086000-T10004', '2013-06-01'),
('C086000-T10004', '2012-07-31'),
('C086000-T10005', '2013-10-01'),
('C086000-T10005', '2012-11-01'),
('C086000-T10006', '2014-04-01'),
('C086000-T10006', '2014-05-15'),
('C086000-T10001', '2014-07-05'),
('C086000-T10003', '2014-03-03');
```

Many thanks!

Comment: So do you need to get all rows for the last one year interval?

Comment: Yes I do need all the rows in order to count them.

Answer (score 0):

The sub query contains all rows joined with the unique max date, and you select only ones which there differente with the max date is smaller than 366 days:

```
select * from
(
SELECT id, date, max(date) over(partition by code) max_date FROM your_table
) A
where max_date - date < interval '366 day'
```

PS: As @a_horse_with_no_name said, you can partition by code to get maximum_date for each code.

Comment: Thanks Houari! The problem in your example is that max date is the same for each row and I need to calculate the difference between the **max date of each code** and the date of the row. I have edited my post to include the creation script of the table I'm testing this on.

Comment: @wiltomap: then use `max(date) over (partition by code) as max_date` instead

Comment: That's it! Many thanks... I'm not very confident with `OVER()` yet.

Comment: Ok, i updated my answer as @a_horse_with_no_name said

Comment: @wiltomap: the Postgres manual contains a nice tutorial: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html